# How to transfer Gel into liquid

Tags: liquids

We’ll know there are few easy method to make liquid into gel form

But whats the method for reverse it

To transfer gel into liquid form

Comment: I suppose to transfer is a wrong verb, implying displacement instead of transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many forms of gels and there is no universal method.

The method with the highest probability of success is heating the gel up, turning it into sol,  but it is temporary and reversible.

Generally, forming gel may involve irreversible 3D linkage, that cannot easily be undone without destruction of gel structure and content.

If chemical structure of gel is known, there can be chosen a reaction leading to  break the polymer structure, if applicable with the overall gel content.